# How to mark the boundries of basic blocks with LLVM or other tools?

Tags: c, compilation, llvm

I'm trying to redo the work of paper 'Neural Machine Translation Inspired Binary Code Similarity Comparison beyond Function Pair', but I failed to complete some components.

The author said '*We modify the backends to add the basic-block boundary annotator, which not only clearly marks the boundaries of blocks, but also annotates a unique ID for each generated assembly block in a way that all assembly blocks compiled from the same IR block* '.

I don't know how to mark the boundaries of a block to determine if several assembly codes for different architectures come from the same source code with LLVM or other tools.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: There are email addresses in such papers. You can write to the authors and ask for their LLVM patch.

Comment: I have sent an email to them. But I don't know why they are not willing to tell me which part they modified.

Comment: @michwqy We have released the code: https://nmt4binaries.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Well, given a `Function` you can iterate over its `BasicBlock`s with `.begin()` and `end()`. This will give you a `BasicBlock`, for which you can always do `.front()` and `.back()` to obtain first and last instruction, respectively. This will give you "boundaries" of each block and the function.

**UPDATE**

I came up with an idea how to do it, if you want "boundaries" to be present in the compiled source.

At the begginning of each function you can generate `store` instructions that would store [blockaddress](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#blockaddress) value for each block of the function. If I'm not mistaken, these would turn into `mov`s at assembly level, one operand of which would be a basic block starting point. This will allow you to infer "boundaries".

Comment: Thanks. But the llvm pass is iterating the basic blocks on llvm IR layer, I don't know how to maintain the boundaries on assembly codes. The purpose of marking boundaries is that if I compile a source code into two assembly codes for different architectures, I can determine if the basic blocks in two assembly codes are from the same source code.

Comment: If that's your goal, that should be quite simple to solve. Call [setDebugLoc()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ae8f5bf5cc06f696b52c709677df00fbf) on the [first non-phi instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a46ef6115027606b67adcf4d28f3dac17) and the terminator of each block. Or just put some on *all* the instructions. Compile with debug info enabled. LLVM will take care to preserve the info you put in your DebugLoc. Normally DebugLoc contains a file name and a line number, but you can pervert that and store a string that identifies the block.

Comment: @michwqy I have updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I find if I get the .ll file with -g by clang, the name of block in IR will remain in the assembly codes. Like this `@ %bb.0:    @ %entry ... .LBB0_1:    @ %if.then`. I don't know if it marks the basic block, but it is enough to help me determine if two pieces of assembly codes are from the same source codes. I will try your idea later.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this problem:

> which not only clearly marks the boundaries of blocks

Each basic block is terminated by a `Terminator` instruction. It can be a branch for example.

> but also annotates a unique ID for each generated assembly block in a way that all assembly blocks compiled from the same IR block '.

This looks like some hashing mechanism. If you iterate over non-dbg instructions and hash_combine each of them to generate a unique ID for each basic block. That should serve the purpose. For example, see how [MergeSimilarFunctions.cpp:profileFunction](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52896) does hashing of each instruction.

One thing to keep in mind would be how to preserve the information created as a result of above hashing. You can add the information as a metadata or print the information to a file somewhere for later reference.